# Security rules Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm struggling with a few security rules, I have the following setup:

[image]

Every user can create a device. And every device can create a room. The relation between an room and device are in the devices rooms table. But I want that some devices can join the room.

I thought that I give them the devices rooms key in this case Kpt_1..... and they need to know 1 device uid that is in there CHttrmpl9fe.... And when that is correct device can join the room. Is this a good approach? And how can I implement that in te security rules?

And no I don't have any security rules right now, because I really don't know how to do this at a good way.

Comment: Firstly, this is very difficult to understand. Could you rephrase your question so that I may be able to further understand what you are trying to do? Thanks!